# NSJSONSerialization sometimes returns null in async request

Tags: ios, request, nsjsonserialization

I've been developing app, that makes asynchronous requests for JSON type of data. Lately, I found strange bug in my code and I can't tell why it is happening.

Ok to the code!

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSError *error=nil;

    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:retrievedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"Retrieved data %@",retrievedData);
}
```

Result is NSDictionary, retrievedData is NSMutableData.
99% of the time, it works fine, connectionDidFinishLoading gets called, and my result is populated. However, in that 1% of the time retrieved data is filled with data, but my result is null.(as you can see on the picture. Could anyone help me please?

[image: Log]

Edit: I get following error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x753e5c0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you take a look at the error first, to see if that gives any indication of what is wrong.

**[edit]**
Your error mentions the reason: `Garbage at end.`.

The response from the webserver is not valid JSON, it contains invalid characters at the end of the output.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to check error... Thanks, updated my question :)

Comment: So problem is not within my code, but actually on server's side? Im asking this, because most of the time it works ok, and we have android app where this never happens :(

Comment: Judging by the error, yes. You can confirm this by converting `retrievedData` to a string to see what the actual content is you receive, and optionally throw this into a JSON validator.

Comment: Hmm you are right, Im using container view with 2 controllers, in both of them I do async request and it seems, they get mixed up somehow and this one is returning response for both of them... Thx alot Joris!

Comment: Ok just for info, I delayed my second request with [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(loadCategories) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; and now it seems to work fine, thx one more time Joris :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. First, look what is a data that wasn't parsed correctly - in my case I did

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:retrievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In my case the reason was - if server sent a few socket.write()'s in a row - all data was received in one single chunk, like

```
{first:json}{second:json}..
```

of course this cannot be parsed as one single json, so I have to introduce delimiter, and split the received buffer into correct chunks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late but nothing online worked for me until I did this:

```
NSString * dataInString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSRange range = [dataInString rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

if(range.location != NSNotFound)
    dataInString = [dataInString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.location+1)];
```

Always worked since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the problem was my server was attaching some extra lines to my json response, that would not appear when i will get the response in my browser. Using  `curl` from terminal you can see the actual output.
The hack was to truncate the extra characters. with json either you have an array or dictionary. Depending on your json structure, you can use the code (as above answer) but look for the comment in line 2

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSBackwardsSearch]; // } for dictionary, ] for array

if(range.location != NSNotFound)
str = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.location+1)];
```

once you get your string clean from garbage data, you can convert it to data again.

```
    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and now from this data you can get your array or dictionary.

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                 JSONObjectWithData:data
                 options:kNilOptions error:&error];  // i used id to be general, you can use array or dictionary structure or later cast this object to as per json
```